# gettext-commons Resource bundle not found

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, internationalization, gettext

I'm working to translate my desktop java application ( on windows 10 OS ), so I'm using gettext-common from http://code.google.com/p/gettext-commons

I have following the tutorial providing by gettext-common : https://code.google.com/archive/p/gettext-commons/wikis/Tutorial.wiki

by following all steps I get create `Messages_fr.class`,`Messages_en.class` the problem is in gettext-common they have Messages_en.properties not .class, when I create Messages_en.properties ( manually ) it works! and I can not do it manually it will take forever (I have more than 700 sentences )

JAVA code :

```
static I18n i18n = I18nFactory.getI18n(ParserTest.class,
            "resources.messages");

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                print("First run");
            } else {
                print("Second run");
                i18n.setLocale(Locale.FRANCE);
            }

            print("Current locale: " + i18n.getLocale());

            print(i18n
                    .tr("This text is marked for translation and is translated"));

            String mark = i18n
                    .marktr("This text is marked for translation but not translated");
            print(mark);
            print(i18n.tr(mark));

            mark = i18n.tr("This is the {0}. text to be translated",
                    "chat (noun)");
            print(mark);

            mark = i18n.tr("This is the {0}. text to be translated",
                    "chat (verb)");
            print(mark);

            print(i18n.tr("chat (noun)"));
            print(i18n.tr("chat (verb)"));

            print("");
        }

    }

    private static void print(String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
```

I have a problem with this:

**Problem 1**: My message files are located under `resources/Messages` directory. It contains only 2 files: messages_en.class and messages_fr.class not messages_fr.properties and messages_en.properties.

If I try to run the above code I'm getting a warning: "ResourceBundle [messages] ,this because there is no .properties files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decide to work with PropertyResourceBundle so I followed all steps and I jump  [msgfmt](http://xnap-commons.sourceforge.net/gettext-commons/gettext-structure.png) ( I'm not going to create  `.class` ) so I use [msgcat](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/msgcat-Invocation.html) with `--properties-output` option to create .properties instead of .class

commend:

```
msgcat --properties-output msgs/fr.po -o src/com/i18n/Messages_fr.properties
```

or create shell script po2pr.sh (./po2pr.sh fr )

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
   echo "Please specify which language_country suffix(es) you want"
   exit 1
fi

for lang in $*
do
  echo "Creating .properties template file for $lang"

  msgcat --properties-output msgs/${lang}.po -o src/com/i18n/Messages_${lang}.properties
 msgs/messages.pot
done
```

java code :

```
public class I {

    private static I18n getI18n() {
        I18n getI18n = I18nFactory.getI18n(I.class, "i18n.Messages");
        Locale Locale = new Locale("fr");
        getI18n.setLocale(Locale);
        return getI18n;
    }

    public static String tr(String str) {
        return getI18n().tr(str);
    }

    public static String tr(String text, Object o1) {
        return getI18n().tr(text, o1);
    }

    public static String tr(String text, Object o1, Object o2) {
        return getI18n().tr(text, o1, o2);
    }

    public static String tr(String text, Object o1, Object o2, Object o3) {
        return getI18n().tr(text, o1, o2, o3);
    }

    public static String tr(String text, Object o1, Object o2, Object o3,
            Object o4) {
        return getI18n().tr(text, o1, o2, o3, o4);
    }

    public static String tr(String text, Object[] objects) {
        return getI18n().tr(text, objects);
    }

}
```

Note:

1-you have to create `Messages_fr.properties`

2- make sure that you create Resource bundle in hue level `src.com.i18n.Messages`

Answer (score 1):

For java ResourceBundle there exist two different implementations:

- PropertyResourceBundle for *.properties files, well known, lazy partial loading
- ListResourceBundle, pure java code, *.class, with arrays, fast, entirely loading (init time, memory usage).

It seems that the gettext bridge uses ListResourceBundle or its own implementation of ResourceBundle from your description. That is okay.

As shown [**msgfmt**](http://xnap-commons.sourceforge.net/gettext-commons/gettext-structure.png) creates from a gettext file (.po) a .class resource file.

The gettext process starts with a template for all languages, the .pot and then per language a .po file.

Their advise on using maven might indeed be worthwile.

**All said, maybe it is just use `Locale.FRENCH`**

**Also I have seen a difference between Properties~ and ListResourceBundles: one might try `"resources/messages"` or attent about the right case (capital M) `"resources.Messages"`**

Comment: Thanks @Joop_Eggen for your reply , Acutely I have tried "resources/messages" and with capital M but still getting Resource bundle not found, now I'm trying to create a jar file contains all .class I'll see if it'll work.